# Laravel Eloquent groupBy orderBy gives different results in MariaDB

Tags: laravel, group-by, eloquent, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I have read about this already in SO and MariaDB knowledgeable about this incompatibility between Mysql and Mariadb. But I am not sure how to resolve this issue in Laravel Eloquent / DB queries.

**My Problem:** The  `groupBy` `orderBy` query gives different results in MariaDB and MySql. It works fine in mySql by the results are in different order in MariaDB.

**This is my query:**

```
$messages = ChatMessages::select(DB::raw('t.*'))
          ->from(DB::raw('(SELECT * FROM chat_messages ORDER BY created_at DESC) t'))
          ->whereIn('message_id', $messageIds)
          ->groupBy('message_id')
          ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
          ->paginate(3);
```

For example, lets say this is the `chat_messages` table:

```
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| id | message_id | created_at        | name      |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 1  | 1000     | 2017-01-01 06:03:40 | Anna      |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 2  | 1007     | 2017-01-02 07:13:20 | Becky     |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 3  | 1000     | 2017-01-03 08:20:12 | Christina |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 4  | 1004     | 2017-01-03 08:20:15 | Dorothy   |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 5  | 1004     | 2017-01-04 09:25:45 | Emma      |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 6  | 1000     | 2017-01-05 10:30:10 | Fiona     |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 7  | 1007     | 2017-01-05 10:33:23 | Gigi      |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 8  | 1007     | 2017-01-06 12:46:34 | Heidi     |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 9  | 1000     | 2017-01-06 12:46:34 | Irene     |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 10 | 1007     | 2017-01-07 14:58:37 | Jane      |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 11 | 1007     | 2017-01-07 14:58:37 | Katy      |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
```

The query works fine in MySql database and the results are returned as this:

```
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| id | message_id | created_at        | name      |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 11 | 1007     | 2017-01-07 14:58:37 | Katy      |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 9  | 1000     | 2017-01-06 12:46:34 | Irene     |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 5  | 1004     | 2017-01-04 09:25:45 | Emma      |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
```

However, in MariaDB database, the results are returned incorrectly like this. It seems to group the `message_id` in ascending order first and then adding the `orderBy` to that:

```
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| id | message_id | created_at        | name      |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 4  | 1004     | 2017-01-03 08:20:15 | Dorothy   |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 2  | 1007     | 2017-01-02 07:13:20 | Becky     |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 1  | 1000     | 2017-01-01 06:03:40 | Anna      |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
```

I tried changing the query thought of using `unique()` instead like this:

```
ChatMessages::whereIn('message_id', $messageIds)
                       ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                       ->paginate(3)
                       ->unique('message_id');
```

Although it works in MariaDB and MySql the same way, but the pagination is applied before the unique check and therefore returned lesser results:

```
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| id | message_id | created_at        | name      |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 11 | 1007     | 2017-01-07 14:58:37 | Katy      |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 9  | 1000     | 2017-01-06 12:46:34 | Irene     |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *probabbly* trying to do a "groupwise max".  This can no longer be done by the trick of having a subquery with an `ORDER BY`.

A subquery, but definition, has no order.  However, in the past, both MariaDB and MySQL would perform the `ORDER BY`, and that happened to be beneficial to the outer query.

MariaDB was first to ignore the inner `ORDER BY`; MySQL picked up on it later.  Follow the tag [greatest-n-per-group] for various workarounds.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Rick. One other workaround I was thinking of doing is do the work using php itself with split queries. As in, first query gets the results using group by and then using php to go through the loop and fetch the latest entry for each. Seems like a lot of additional queries when compared to the previous joint statement. I will read through to see if there are any other workarounds for me.